# Unable to read text from csv into dataframe when text is "null" and "nan"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to upload Google n-gram word frequency data into a dataframe.

Dataset can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/wheelercode/dictionary-word-frequency

A couple of words are not loading unfortunately. The word "null" appears on row 9156 of the csv file and the word "nan" appears on row 17230 of the csv file.

[image]

[image]

This is how I am uploading the data

```
my_freq_df = pd.read_csv('ngram_freq_dict.csv',  dtype = {"word": str, "count": np.int32} ) 
my_freq_df['word'] = my_freq_df['word'].astype("string")
```

Unfortunately, when I try to check if those words were loaded as strings, I get that they weren't

```
count = 0

for index, row in my_freq_df.iterrows():
    count += 1
    try:
        len(row['word'])
    except:
        print(row['word'])
        print(count)
        print("****____*****")
```

We can see the image of the output of the try, except and we can see that I cant calculate the length of the words "nan" and "null". Both words are being read as NA.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas treats a certain set of values as "NA" by default, but you can explicitly tell it to ignore those defaults with `keep_default_na=False`. "null" and "nan" both happen to be in that list!

```py
my_freq_df = pd.read_csv(
    'ngram_freq_dict.csv',
    dtype = {"word": str, "count": np.int32},
    keep_default_na=False
)
```

As of today, the complete set of strings that it treats as NA by default is:

```py
[
 "", "#N/A", "#N/A N/A", "#NA", "-1.#IND", "-1.#QNAN", "-NaN", 
 "-nan", "1.#IND", "1.#QNAN", "<NA>", "N/A", "NA", "NULL",
 "NaN", "n/a", "nan", "null"
]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: is there some way to customize the list of stings that is treated as NA?

Comment: Yep! Use the `na_values` parameter. In the docs it's right next to `keep_default_na`. You'll need to use both if you want to exclude the defaults and define your own.